# WPF проверить виден ли визуальный объект

Tags: c#, wpf

Каким образом можно проверить что визуальный объект виден пользователю, и его необходимо отрисовать, в противном случае ничего не делать пока не станет видим?

В вопросе речь не о свойстве `Visibility`, а именно о поле видимости.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте свойство [IsVisible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisible(v=vs.110).aspx):

> При определении значения `IsVisible` учитываются все факторы компоновки.
>   `Visibility`, которое является настраиваемым свойством,
>   указывает только на намерение программно сделать элемент видимым или
>   невидимым.

Comment: Хм, жаль оно с `FrameworkElement` не работает =)

Comment: Почему не работает? FrameworkElement это же наследник UIElement